# How many different functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ are there if $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm not quite sure of what this question is asking. Can someone explain please

Comment: It's asking exactly what it says: if $A$ is a set of $m$ elements, and $B$ is a set of $n$ elements, how many functions are there from $A$ to $B$? In other words, in how many ways can you choose which element of $B$ to map each element of $A$ to?

Comment: No absolute value here. Just number of elements, which just happens to be written using the same notation as absolute value.

Comment: then isn't there an infinite number of elements?

Comment: @user3239138 Certainly not! Say that $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m\}$.  How many ways can you choose which element of $B$ will be $f(a_1)$?  How about $f(a_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

When $A$ is a set, $|A|$ is intended to mean the *cardinality* of $A$--the number of elements of $A.$

So, $A$ is a set with $m$ elements and $B$ is a set with $n$ elements.

Now, to build a function $f:A \to B,$ for each $a\in A$ we must pick a specific $b\in B$ to call "$f(a).$" Given any $a\in A,$ how many ways are there for us to pick such a $b\in B$? For how many $a\in A$ must we do this? What does that tell you about the number of ways we can make a function $f:A \to B$?

If it helps, start with some small sets $A$ and $B$ and see if you can develop a pattern based on the number of elements in each. For example:

$$A=\{1\},B=\{z\}\\ A=\{1\},B=\{y,z\}\\ A=\{1\},B=\{x,y,z\}\\ A=\{1\},B=\{w,x,y,z\}\\ A=\{1,2\},B=\{z\}\\ A=\{1,2\},B=\{y,z\}\\ A=\{1,2\},B=\{x,y,z\}\\ A=\{1,2,3\},B=\{z\}\\ A=\{1,2,3\},B=\{y,z\}$$

Answer (score 1):

The set of all functions $A\to B$ is sometimes denoted $B^A$, exactly because when $A,B$ are finite then there are $|B|^{|A|}$ (in the question $n^m$) functions. This is so because for every element $a\in A$ there are $|B|$ possibilities for $f(a)$, and these $|A|$ choices are entirely independent and together determine $f$. Numbers of independent choices need to be multiplied to get the number of combined choices.

In particular there is $n^0=1$ such function when $A$ is empty (whether or not $B$ is so), and otherwise if $B$ is empty there are $0^m=0$ (with $m>0$) such functions.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: For every $a_i$ in $A$, there are $n$ elements in $B$ to which it can map. Try to proceed from here.

---

**SPOILERS BELOW**

---

Let $A=\{a_1,a_2, \cdots,a_m\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2, \cdots,b_n\}$

There are $n$ possible values for $f(a_1)$, namely, $b_1,b_2, \cdots,b_n$. Similarly, there are $n$ possible values for each $f(a_i)$.

Thus net number of ways to map $A$ to $B = n*n*n*\cdots*n =n^m$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B^A$ denote the set of all the maps from $A$ to $B$

Claim : If $A,B$ are finite then $\#( B^A)= \#B^{\#A}$

Proof: We induct on the cardinality of $A$. If the set is empty only we have the empty function (why?) and so $\#( B^A)= \#B^{\#A}$. Now suppose we have already proven the assertion for all sets of size $n$. Let $\#A=n+1$. The set is non-empty, in particular there is a $x_0 \in A$. Define $A'= A\setminus\{x_0\}$. By inductive hypothesis we have $\#( B^{A'})= \#B^{\#A'}$.

Now we claim that  $B^A \simeq B^{A'}\times B$ (i.e., there exists a bijective map). Define  $f\mapsto(f\restriction_ {A'},f(x_0))$ (why is this a bijection?). Then $\# (B^A) = \# (B^{A'}) \cdot \#B=\#B^{\#A'}\cdot\#B=\#B^{\#A}$, notice that $\# A = \#A'+1$.

as was to be shown.